# smartgwt beginner- how to set an image to 100% of available width in HLayout

Tags: smartgwt

I am working on a java web app with SmartGWT for the UI, in it I am using a wide-logo image in the following manner--

```
    Img logo = new Img("hlogo.png", 607, 113 );
    Label name = new Label();
    HLayout westLayout = new HLayout();
    westLayout.setHeight(HEADER_AREA_HEIGHT);    
    westLayout.setWidth("70%");
    westLayout.addMember(logo);
    westLayout.addMember(name);
```

How do I set the width so that it automatically scales to 100% of the width of the 'westLayout' (of type HLayout)

Answer (score 0):

logo.setWidth100();
will extend the logo to 100% of layout size.  However, your logo might not keep its size and height scaled.  If you want to set height, width to 607,113 as you're doing it, then you're doing it the right way !!